# How does the actual elimination of dependent coordinates takes place?

Tags: classical-mechanics

In the textbooks of classical mechanics I have been through, it is often quoted that, given an $N$ particle system having $3N$ Cartesian coordinates $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ connected by $r$ holonomic constraints $\phi(x_i,y_i,z_i,t)=0$, any $r$ of the $3N$ coordinates *can be eliminated*........ . How? For instance, I began with $3N$ equations of motion,
$$
\ddot {x_i}=X_i,
$$
$$
\ddot {y_i}=Y_i,
$$
$$
\ddot {z_i}=Z_i,
$$
Then I differentiated the constraint equations twice to get $r$ equations of the form;
$$
\sum_i \phi_{x_i} \ddot {x_i}  + \sum_i \phi_{y_i} \ddot {y_i} + \sum_i \phi_{z_i} \ddot {z_i} + c =0,
$$
where $c$ depends on the quantities $\dot {x_i}$,...,$\phi_{x_iy_j}$., etc. So now I have $r$ linear equations in $3N$ variables $\ddot {x_i},\ddot {y_i},\ddot {z_i}$ as well as the original $3N$ equations in these variables. My question is, how do I eliminate any $r$ of *these* $3N$ variables (i.e. the actual acceleration components)? By some substitution? Or by setting up the $3N \times r$ matrix equation? Thanks!

Comment: Is it a conceptual or technical issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot in your equations the constraint forces:

for the free body diagram (1 particle) with constraint equations   you obtain:

$$m\ddot x=F_x+F_{cx}$$
$$m\ddot y=F_y+F_{cy}$$
$$m\ddot z=F_z+F_{cz}$$

in vector notation

$$m\,\vec{\ddot{w}}=\vec{{F}}_a+\vec{{F}}_c\tag 1$$
where $\vec F_a~$ is  the applied force and $\vec F_c~$ is the constraint force

and the constraint equations

$$\vec\phi(\vec w)=\vec 0$$

with :
$$\vec{{F}}_c=\left[\frac{\partial \vec \phi}{\partial \vec w}\right]^T\,\vec{\lambda}=\boldsymbol C_b^T\,\vec \lambda$$

where $\vec \lambda~$ is the generalized constraint force

thus Eq. (1):

$$m\,\vec{\ddot{w}}=\vec{{F}}_a+\boldsymbol C_b^T\,\vec \lambda\tag 2$$

to solve Eq. (2) you differentiate twice the constraint equation  and obtain

$$\boldsymbol C_b\,\vec{\ddot{w}}+\frac {d}{dt}\boldsymbol C_b=\vec 0\tag 3$$

with Eq (2) and (3) you  obtain $~\vec{\ddot{w}}~$ and $~\vec \lambda$

you can also write Eq (2) and (3) in matrix notation

$$\boldsymbol A\,\boldsymbol z=\boldsymbol b$$

where :

$$\boldsymbol z=\begin{bmatrix}
   \vec{\ddot{w}} \\
    \vec \lambda\\
 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\boldsymbol b=\begin{bmatrix}
   \vec{F}_A \\
    -\frac {d}{dt}\boldsymbol C_b\\
 \end{bmatrix}~,\frac {d}{dt}\boldsymbol C_b=\frac{ \partial \left[\boldsymbol C_b\,\vec{\dot{w}}\right]}{\partial \vec w}\,\vec{\dot{w}}$$

and

$$\boldsymbol A=\begin{bmatrix}
    m\,E_3 & -\boldsymbol C_b^T \\
    \boldsymbol C_b & \boldsymbol 0 \\
  \end{bmatrix}$$

**Remark**

to solve the differential equations you need  the initial conditions those must full filled the constraint equations $~\vec \phi(\vec w)=\vec 0$

**Example: 3D Pendulum**

the applied force is:

$$\vec F_a=\begin{bmatrix}
     0 \\
     0 \\
     -m\,g \\
   \end{bmatrix}$$

the constraint equation is:

$$\phi=x^2+y^2+z^2-L^2=0$$

$\rightarrow$

$$\boldsymbol C_b=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 2\,x&2\,y&2\,z\end {array} \right] $$

$$\frac{d}{dt}\boldsymbol C_b=
\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 2\,\dot x^2&2\,\dot y^2&2\,\dot z^2\end {array} \right] $$

$$\boldsymbol A=\left[ \begin {array}{cccc} m&0&0&-2\,x\\ 0&m&0&-2
\,y\\ 0&0&m&-2\,z\\-2\,x&-2\,y&-2
\,z&0\end {array} \right] 
$$

$$\boldsymbol b=    \left[ \begin {array}{c} 0\\0\\ 
-mg\\ -2\,{{\dot x}}^{2}-2\,{{\dot y}}^{2}-2\,{{\dot z}}^{2}\end {array} \right]$$

$\Rightarrow$

$$\boldsymbol z=\left[ \begin {array}{c} {\frac {x \left( z\,g+{{\dot{x}}}^{2}+{{\dot{y}}
}^{2}+{{\dot{z}}}^{2} \right) }{{L}^{2}}}\\  {\frac {y
 \left( z\,g+{{\dot{x}}}^{2}+{{\dot{y}}}^{2}+{{\dot{z}}}^{2} \right) }{{L}^
{2}}}\\  -{\frac {g\,{x}^{2}+g\,{y}^{2}-z{{\dot{x}}}^{2}-z
{{\dot{y}}}^{2}-z{{\dot{z}}}^{2}}{{L}^{2}}}\\  \frac 12\,{
\frac {m \left( z\,g+{{\dot{x}}}^{2}+{{\dot{y}}}^{2}+{{\dot{z}}}^{2}
 \right) }{{L}^{2}}}\end {array} \right]
$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider an example. There is just one particle with coordinates $(x,y,z)$ and the constraint is that it moves on a plane given by $z=0$. If it is too simple, consider a constraint in a somewhat more abstract form, say, $\phi(x,y,z)=0$. If you can express one of the coordinates form the last equation in the form, for instance, $z=f(x,y)$ you are done. If not, you can always use the method of Lagrange multipliers.